# How to stop untill setstate exectues in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an logout functionality. By which when user clicks on logout button, they will be prompted a dialog asking "Are you sure that you want to logout ? ". For Dialog , i have used a package named [react-native-popup-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-dialog).

Actually, whats happening is as this app is clubbed with redux. I used action for logout functionality. And for dialog , i have used component level state.

My Dialog Code:

```
<Dialog
              visible={this.state.showDialog}
              dialogTitle={
              <DialogTitle 
              title="Confirm Logging Out"
              textStyle={{ fontSize: 15 }} 
              />}
              width={0.8}
              footer={
                  <DialogFooter>
                    <DialogButton
                      text="CANCEL"
                      textStyle={{ fontSize: 14 }}
                      onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({ showDialog: false });
                      }}
                    />
                    <DialogButton
                      text="CONFIRM"
                      textStyle={{ fontSize: 14 }}
                      onPress={() => {
                          this.onLogoutPress();
                      }}
                    />
                  </DialogFooter>
                }
              onTouchOutside={() => {
              this.setState({ showDialog: false });
              }}
          >
              <DialogContent>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, top: 10 }}>Are you sure you want to logout ?</Text>
              </DialogContent>
          </Dialog>
```

And my Logout Button Code:

```
         <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.setState({ showDialog: true})}
                        >
                        <CardItem>
                            <Icon name="log-out"
                            style={{ color: '#03A9F4' }}
                            />
                            <Body>
                                <Text>
                                    Logout
                                </Text>
                            </Body>
                            <Right>
                                <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                            </Right>
                        </CardItem>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
```

So my onLogoutPress() code:

```
onLogoutPress() {
    this.setState({ showDialog: false });

    this.props.logOut(() => {
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetActionToWelcome);
    })
}
```

The issue , i am facing is that. When i click on confirm button the "onLogoutPress()" shoots up, and the dialog is not closing instead of that the resetAction of react navigation shoots up.  As setstate is async function i think it took time to get back, within that the logout action is shoots up and app gets start from splash screen. But till the dialog is kept open.

How to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2nd argument of `setState`

```
onLogoutPress() {
    this.setState({ showDialog: false },() => {
        this.props.logOut(() => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetActionToWelcome);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: doing clubbed call backs wont create a problem in performance ?

Comment: It is not clubbed call, its functionality of setState, once there is change in state done you will get a callback so you can perform rest of opertion

Comment: I tried, but still the dialog is opened ! Its not closing even after using the callback you said ! `onLogoutPress() {
        this.setState({ showDialog: false }, () => {
            this.props.logOut(() => {
                this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetActionToWelcome);
                console.log(this.state.showDialog);
            })
        })
    };` My updated code

Comment: Does your `Dialog` code and `onLogoutPress()` is in the same component?

Comment: yes ! As i couldnt reset the stack from redux action. I used a callback and resetting the stack in onLogoutPress() which is same component

Comment: Any idea about what to do ?

Comment: Hey , can you please update the answer ? Regarding the issue I stated

Comment: Hey brother ?could you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

`setState` has a callback which you can use to perform action after the state change is complete

```
setState({myvar: "updateval"}, () => {
  //Do something after the state is changed
})
```